# PPLNS is good against pool hoping?

Tags: mining-pools

Is this true?

miningpoolhub.com use PPLNS

https://miningpoolhub.com/?page=account&action=balances

They said it's hopping proof.

Is this true? There is no way to adjust that?

So there is some luck involved? If after we mine we got a coin quickly our share may be doubled if the next one is also short.

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/what-is-pool-hopping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PPLNS is protected against pool hopping. That is the purpose of PPLNS. If it  wasn't then pools would use proportional payouts rather than PPLNS.

Yes, there is luck involved. There is ONLY luck involved. That is how it is pool hopper safe.

If you were able, at the time you do some work, to know whether that work would be paid well or poorly then you could abuse the pool with pool hopping. But with PPLNS you just have to wait and see - you can't know in advance.

There are some (very vocal) people who say they can pool hop PPLNS because they can tell the future. Don't be one of those guys. Educate yourself.

If you want to know the details of mining pool reward systems then  I suggest reading Meni Rosenfeld's paper on the matter. See https://bitcoil.co.il/pool_analysis.pdf or https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4980

Also see [What is pool hopping?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5072/what-is-pool-hopping)